# Git Large files detected

Tags: git

I performed some load testing by using JMeter and then tried to checkin my project into git

by doing

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

I got an error message

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 50.13 MiB | 13.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: File java_pid32554.hprof is 412.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.dev.myc.com/p/p.git
 ! [remote rejected] feature/branch -> feature/branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.dev.myc.com/p/p.git'
```

To resolve the error I did the following

```
git rm java_pid32554.hprof
rm java_pid32554.hprof
added */*.hprof to .gitignore
```

Now I can see that the offending file is deleted from local file system. To be sure I also did a search

```
MacBook-Pro:p (feature/branch>)$ sudo find / -name java_pid32554.hprof
Password:
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
MacBook-Pro:p (feature/branch>)$
```

So the file is indeed gone.

Now when I try

git push

it again gives the same error message.... even though the file is deleted.

I will not mark this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

My question presents a direct error message from git and the answer below is much more clear and direct. The other thread is cluttered with different types of solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first approach assumes that you don't care about "tracking" the large file; and consequently don't care to keep a copy of it on GitHub. In that case, you'll need to *"go back in time"* to an earlier commit; to a commit before you added the large, offending file.

You can do the following to do that:

```
git tag too_big            # a "savepoint" just in case you care for it later
git log                    # find an earlier COMMIT_ID
git reset --hard COMMIT_ID # replace COMMIT_ID with the one found

# See how things are at this point
git status
```

If it's not clean after "git status", maybe you'd be interested in:

```
# Optionally, this will wipe things out
git clean -df
```

And then continuing your work from that point.

```
git push master     # assuming your branch is master
```

The tag will give you a point of reference if you ever need to restore that giant file. It will also cause problems when you try to push to GitHub, and thus, push only `master` as opposed to a general purpose (ambiguous) `git push` (possibly implying `--all`).

---

Alternatively, if you must apply "source code control" to the very large file for some reason, you can explore GitHub's LFS (Large File Storage) git extension.

https://git-lfs.github.com/

It might be wise to have a git sub-repository (officially known as submodule) for handling large files.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue and didn't want to revert back to an earlier version. The option I chose was to copy the repository elsewhere, clone it again and then overwrite the files with the original (except the large file).

Comment: Brilliant. The other 'solutions' were so complicated and confusing. My problem was that the earliest version was the very first one. And I didn't want to lose other changes either. TY.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your local git has a history of the large file. In git, the history contains the full file, even if it's been deleted in the latest version, this is so that you can undo a change. To get around this, you'll need to rewrite history, or revert the git repo to an earlier revision.

see the related link: [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit?rq=1)